# Struts 2 select tag returns "The requested list key 'X' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type"

Tags: struts2

I'm beginner in Struts 2. I am trying an example from [this site](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/). I then tried executing the code in eclipse, but I had an error.

I got error like:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
tag 'select', field 'list', name 'yourSearchEngine': The requested list key 'searchEngine' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.fieldError(Component.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.findValue(Component.java:358)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.ListUIBean.evaluateExtraParams(ListUIBean.java:80)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Select.evaluateExtraParams(Select.java:105)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:856)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:510)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.Select_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fselect_005f0(Select_jsp.java:166)
    at org.apache.jsp.Select_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(Select_jsp.java:113)
    at org.apache.jsp.Select_jsp._jspService(Select_jsp.java:71)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Is your list accessible on the client side? have you tried printing it using iterator tag? Are you sure you have correct getter/setter for this list?First do a debug for the above

Comment: It looks like that example is confusing for new users. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435554/struts2-problem-with-sselect

Comment: [Here's](http://www.ziddu.com/download/17049585/Struts2Select.rar.html) a working Netbeans 6.9 project demonstrating select tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
The requested list key 'searchEngine' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location] at
```

The problem lies here, there is no searchEngine list on the request

How are you "executing" the example?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are actually populating the data into select tag before it is displayed. I mean try to populate the data into select tag in your action class itself. Take a list in your request class and pass that list name as list attribute in that select tag.

Comment: make sure the list is in request action class not in the result action class. Regards Sai Rajesh